# I need help editing this question about a hypothetical matriarchal society

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, asking-questions, suggested-edits

I had asked this before and it was closed, so I would like some feedback on how I can narrow it down. In this worldbuilding scenario, pregnancy would be an active rather than passive process. A woman could biologically determine the sex of their child in the womb and make it a boy or girl. They could choose whether to carry it to term or abort it completely. Rate of gestation could be controlled, sped up or slowed down as needed. Birth would be a painless or maybe even enjoyable experience. Exteme stress would be detrimental to the pregnancy, and the baby's health could be adversely affected or cause its death.
The question was: would these advantages be enough to justify or lead to a matriarchal society?

[Could the biological capability to control their reproductive process justify a matriarchal society forming?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/69568/)

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a link to the [original question](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/69568/would-a-matriarchal-society-have-developed-if-women-had-the-biological-capabilit) so people can see for themselves how the change history is and what the comments/close-reasons were.

Comment: @Secespitus you could have added it, too, and just leave comment. No point in leaving such minor task waiting :)

Comment: @Molot No, I cannot edit this post. Otherwise I would have done it. There is no button to edit the post.

Comment: Oh. Well, I did it. I admit, I don't remember what she rep levels to edit / suggest an edit on meta. Believed them to be same as on main site, apparently they aren't.

Comment: @Mołot When I hover over the button I see the text "Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites." So there is no such thing as a suggested edit on the Meta for any normal post. It seems like I need the normal 2k rep edit privilege on main to be able to edit normal posts here on Meta.

Comment: We have a [Sandbox](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) specifically for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is fine. It is hard to answer as there are many aspects to the question patriarchy vs. matriarchy but I wouldn't say that this is not answerable.

A problem with your original question before your recent edit was that you had multiple questions, one of them being "What would be the social ramifications of this?". This is almost always too broad. But with the focus solely on matriarchy it should be fine.

I think this question can be posted. You should edit your original question and see what other users with more experience say about this.

---

For reference: [Here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35696571#35696571) is my first reaction to the OP posting on Meta and asking for help in chat.

[Here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35852101#35852101) are my comments on this topic I posted in the chat after some time where Pavel responded that the question is okay.

[Here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35934671#35934671) is another discussion about this topic that was moved from [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/73330/could-these-changes-early-in-human-history-lead-to-a-matriarchial-society-develo) question to the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55084/discussion-on-question-by-shard-martin-could-these-changes-early-in-human-histor) where OP asked for feedback.

The question currently has 3 Upvotes and no negative comments after the most recent edit by OP, as well as no negative feedback in this Meta-Post so it should be reopened.

Comment: +1 I voted too broad because of was many questions in one, and somehow unclear (as already mentioned in comments). Last edit fixed a lot.

Comment: So where do I go from here? How many votes do I need?

Comment: @Shardmartin as with closure - you need 5 votes from people of 3k rep. Now you have 2 votes to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

I made a further change, just to the Title line.

The way you asked it in the body is better: *could* rather than *would*, and *justify* rather than cause-to-happen.

Is it reasonable to happen in your story, as opposed to would that be a certain outcome under those conditions.